# angularjs check if key allready exist and if not exist push it to scope inside foreach loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

im geting data from Db using php at first for building a table , later im geting new json data from socket and updating $scope, what i need is to push values that not exist in $scope.

```
angular.forEach(event.market, (market ,keym) => {

   angular.forEach($scope.users.results, function(value, key) {

   if(value.marketId == keym) // keym = new marketId from socket
   {
     //do nothing
   }
  else
  {
     //push(new valuse);  
  }


   });
});
```

the problem im having is that if a marketId dosent match any keys that i allready have then it pushes the amount of times it didnt match instead of pushing 1 time if it didnt match.
what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that solved my issue :

```
angular.forEach(game.market, (market, keym) => {

  var addToArray = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.results.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.users.results[i].marketId == keym) {
      addToArray = false;
    }
  }
  if (addToArray) {


    $scope.users.results.push({
      marketId: keym,
      marketName: market.name
    });

  }

  $scope.users.results.marketName = ' ';
  $scope.users.results.marketId = ' ';

});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before doing push into some array, check whether marketId dose not match any keys and not present in array as well. So in else you will have to add conditions for marketId check and array check.

Comment: this is what im doing but the missing key dosent match any of the keys then it pushes the new key the times that it dosent match , if a key doesnt match 10 keys then it pushes 10 times

Comment: Can you please show some example sample of input and ouput?

Comment: if i got market ids: 1,2,3,4 and im getting new data from socket : ids 1,2,3,6 then i need to find that 6 do not exist, in my forEach loop im getting 4 times that 6 do not exist and its pushing id 6 four times because it do not match any of the ids, i want to  push 1 time, what can i do to make the code work and tell me that only id 6 is not present? thanks

Comment: arr1=[1,2,3,4];
arr2=[1,2,3,6]
filteredarr = arr2.filter(e => !arr1.includes(e));
arr1.concat(filtered)

Comment: thanks Saima for your help is this can work in forEach loop and check each arr2 array against arr1, is it going to find the missing array once and show me one time that array number 6 is not found? or its going to tell me that 4 times? , can you show some code example in forEach loop? thank you very very much for your help

Comment: If you want to test it. Copy paste it on your browser console. And if you use filter and include then I guess you will not need foreach

Comment: i did it allready in my code and its including array 6 , but dosent solve my issue , i need it in side my for each loop and to check if keym is exist or not but not telling me that the amount of time its not equal to keys i allready have, i need it one time ,thanks again

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to add in an array, missing objects. I think what you are trying to do can be simply achieved by:

```
angular.forEach(event.market, (valueM, keyM) => {
  let isDuplicate = $scope.users.results.filter(user => /* some validation here */).length > 0;

  if(!isDuplicate) {
    // push new values
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but i dont understand the : /* some validation here */ , im new to angularJs :)

Comment: that validation is to check if object already exists in `$scope.users.results` so that you don't have any duplicates. `Array.filter` is a es6 javascript function. Considering a user has an `ID`, what you would do is a `$scope.users.results.filter(user => user.id === valueM).length > 0` which translates to get all users where user id is value, if that array has elements, then there are duplicates. Its not as much angularjs as it is javascript